# Getting comparison score from OpenCv image comparison

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am trying to write a function in OpenCv for comparing two images - imageA and imageB, to check to what extent they are similar.

I want to arrive at three comparison scores(0 to 100 value) as shown below. 
1. **Histograms** - compareHist() : OpenCV method 
2. **Template Matching** - matchTemplate() : OpenCV method 
3. **Feature Matching** - BFMatcher() : OpenCV method

Above on the scores derived from the above calculations I want to arrive at a conclusion regarding the matching. 
I was successful in getting this functions to work, but not at getting a comparison score for it. I would be great if someone could help me with that. Also, any other advice regarding this sort of image matching is also welcome.

I know there are different kind of algorithms that can be used for the above functions. So, just clarifying on the kind of images that I will be using. 
1. As mentioned above it will be a one-to-one comparison. 
2. Its all images taken by a human using a mobile camera. 
3. The images that match will be taken of the same object/place from the same spot mostly. (Accoding to the time of the day, the lighting could differ) 
4. If the images doesn't match the user will be asked to click another one, till it matches. 
5. The kind of images compared could include - corridor, office table, computer screen(content on the screen to be compared), pepper document etc.

Comment: Post your code that works to prevent code writen in all kinds of directions except for the one you are interested in. Hence, there is no need to re-invent the wheel ;-) In addition, post also the code part where "but not at getting a comparison score for it" applies to. And above all add language specificity... C++, C# or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- With histogram you can get a comparison score using **histogram intersection**. If you divide the **intersection** of two histograms to the **union** of the two histogram, will give you a score between **0** (no match at all) and **1** (complete match) like the example in the below graph:

[image]

You can compute the intersection for histogram with a simple For loop.

2- In template matching, the score you get is different for each method of comparing. In this [link](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) you can see the details of each method. In some methods highest score means the best match, but in some others, the lowest score means the most matched. For defining a score between 0 and 1, you should consider 2 scores: one for matching an image with itself (most match score) and two, matching two completely different images (lowest match) and then **normalize** the scores by the number of pixels in the image (**height*width**).

3- Feature matching is different than the last two methods. You may have two similar image with poor features (which fail in matching) or having two conceptually different images and have many matched features. Although if the images are feature-rich we can define something as a score. For this purpose, consider this example:

- Img1 has 200 features
- Img2 has 170 features
- These two images have 100 matched features
- Consider 0.5 (100/200) as the whole image matching score

You can also involve the distances between the matched pairs of features into the scoring but I think that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comparison score. Have you tried implementing a weighted average to get a final comparison metric? Weight the 3 matching methods you are implementing according to their accuracy, the best method gets the “heaviest” weight.

Also, if you want to explore additional matching methods, give FFT-based matching a try: http://machineawakening.blogspot.com/2015/12/fft-based-cosine-similarity-for-fast.html